# Can i change the priority of observers for observeValueForKeyPath?

Tags: objective-c

I inherited a lot of code in which stuff is recalculated when certain options change (Userdefaults).
I implemented a master-element (lets just call it that) that determines options based on the changes made to the userdefaults. However, because it is registered first, it seems to receive calls last. Now the sub-modules are notified of a change, ask the master what to do, but the master does not yet know, that there is/will be a change.

In theory the subs should observe the master and be notified by it but the code is extensive and rerouting all those calls would cost a lot of time so i'm looking for a way to make sure the master is called first and then the others.

Answer (score 0):

No. Observers cannot rely on order of notification. Typically you deal with this by observing with `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` so that you will be passed the new value in the callback rather than asking another object for it.